# How to know which file or script is running current element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

Suppose, I have a slider which contains a javascript file and the script I want to change for that but there are multiple files containing this javascript file. So now I would like to know which file or script exactly has been run to current element that `i.e. slider`. Is there any way to know?

Answer (score 1):

Let see I want to know the script of the slider to which we can inspect I'm using firebug here and find the current running script. The following picture describes the steps to find out which script is run for current element (i.e. slider):

[image]

We know in the last step (6) the file name is navigationf.js in which the current script is running.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript profiler in chrome dev tools.