# Clicking an element in a page and see the related JavaScript code(s)

Tags: javascript

There are many JavaScript codes in a page but I want to see when I click a link or a button or any other element in a page what JavaScript code(s) will be exclusively activated or will be involved in the process. Is there any program for this?  Does firebug or other similar program have this capability?

Comment: This will help you :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181340/how-to-know-which-file-or-script-is-running-current-element/21181410#21181410

Comment: In Chrome Developer tool, click on that element using inspector, click on Event listener, find the one event listener you want (eg. click).